# Как перевести конструкцию 'if/else' в условную операцию '?'

Tags: javascript, node.js

Доброе утро, мне хочется оптимизировать этот код:

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 == choice2) {
    console.log("Ничья");
  } else if (choice1 == 'Камень'){
    if (choice2 == 'Ножницы') {
      console.log('Камень побеждает ножницы');
    } else {
      console.log('Бумага побеждает камень');
    }
  } else if (choice1 == 'Ножницы'){
    if (choice2 == 'Бумага') {
      console.log('Ножницы побеждают бумагу');
    } else {
      console.log('Камень побеждает ножницы');
    }
  } else if (choice1 == 'Бумага'){
    if (choice2 == 'Камень') {
      console.log('Бумага побеждает камень');
    } else {
      console.log('Ножницы побеждают бумагу');
    }
  } 
}
```

Вот пробую, но выдает или `"Ничья"` либо `'Камень побеждает ножницы'`

```
var choice = (userChoice == computerChoice) ? "Ничья" :
  (userChoice == 'Камень') && (computerChoice == 'Ножницы') ? 'Бумага побеждает камень' :
  'Камень побеждает ножницы' ;
  (userChoice == 'Ножницы') && (computerChoice == 'Бумага') ? 'Камень побеждает ножницы' :
  'Ножницы побеждают бумагу' ;
  (userChoice == 'Бумага') && (computerChoice == 'Камень') ? 'Ножницы побеждают бумагу' :
  'Бумага побеждает камень' ;

  console.log(choice);
```

Вопрос:
В чем моя ошибка, можно ли так делать? Еще хотелось бы узнать возможно ли это с конструкцией `swith()`

Comment: ошибка в `;` - точка с запятой должна стоять только в конце выражения, ну и условия должны все быть а не только одна ветка как сейчас

Comment: Спасибо, за развернутый ответ, и хорошую альтернативу!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не стоит использовать тернарный оператор, если предполагается много ветвей, так как в этом случае код станет более запутанным.

В коде из вопроса присутствует несколько ошибок:

Например, перепутаны результаты

```
(userChoice == 'Камень') && (computerChoice == 'Ножницы') ? 'Бумага побеждает камень'
```

А так же беспорядочно стоят `;`. Оператор *точка с запятой* разделяет выражения, но тут должно было быть *только одно* выражение. А сейчас их три, и в переменную `choice` сохраняется только значение первого.

Кроме того проверяется всего три условия, в то время как в исходной функции - шесть.

Для решения можно вообще отказаться от условий

Например:

```js
function compare(choice1, choice2) {
  if (choice1 == choice2) {
    return "Ничья";
  }
  var choices = {
    "Камень": 1,  // 001
    "Ножницы": 2, // 010
    "Бумага": 4   // 100
  };

  var result = {
    [choices["Камень"] | choices["Ножницы"]]: "Камень побеждает ножницы",
    [choices["Камень"] | choices["Бумага"]]: "Бумага побеждает камень",
    [choices["Бумага"] | choices["Ножницы"]]: "Ножницы побеждают бумагу"
  };
  return result[choices[choice1] | choices[choice2]];
}

document.body.innerHTML += (compare("Бумага", "Камень")) + '<br/>';
document.body.innerHTML += (compare("Камень", "Камень")) + '<br/>';
document.body.innerHTML += (compare("Ножницы", "Камень")) + '<br/>';
document.body.innerHTML += (compare("Бумага", "Ножницы")) + '<br/>';
```